# How can I change Kendo Grid Filter UI?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I use Grid kendo to show my data. 
in my query I use this field:

public Nullable Date { get; set; }

When I enable filterable i get date picker for select date. but i want this filter behavior like string . 
I use this code :

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Date).Width("10%").Title("Date").Filterable(x=>x.UI(GridFilterUIRole.Default));
```

and don't work correctly . 
so what must i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
col.Bound(c => c.ETA).ClientTemplate("#: kendo.toString(ETA? new Date(ETA):ETA,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm')#").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm }").Title("ETA").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = "ETA" })
```

ETA is a string property I am converting datetime to string in c# function at back-end.

Its not a permanent solution, but I am using this in live system and it working fine till now ;)

Edit: `columns.Bound(p => p.Date).Width("10%").Title("Date").Filterable(true);`

I don't know what is `x=>x.UI(GridFilterUIRole.Default)`

set the `Date` property as `string` type in your model so `kendo grid` will treat it like `string`. and it will pass the filter value as `string` to your `action method` too

Comment: you can skip the .ClientTemplate("#: kendo.toString(ETA? new Date(ETA):ETA,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm')#") part

Comment: it doesn't  matter for me to show date pattern and any thing . i just need remove date picker in filter toolbar and force textbox to accept any string and pass to ActionResult .

Comment: you can skip the format stuff and I have commented, the ETA property is type of string so your grid filter will not show date picker it will show you the string filter options.

Comment: It's doesn't work for me . I save information in database into datetime field and i can't change it as soon as possible.  I need something else like this code i wrote in main question . by this code "GridFilterUIRole.Default" you can change UI of filter part view like time span or date picker and more . but this is no option for regular string . and  i don't know what must i do ....

Comment: see if some how we have converted the date time filter to string, how the `ToDataSourceResult` suppose to work, I mean you have to convert date time to string for filtering records. That's why I suggest you to show data as string and convert string to date time while saving in data base.

Comment: In my project Date save in AD format (like 12/8/2016) and the datepicker filter show this format. but my clients use Persian Date and i must convert date to Persian format . so i can do it and convert and show date in Persian Format. but when i want use filter i have some big problem. in my way i try to convert date to string that the users must type date and filter it. so i must convert date to string and then in actionresult i convert again this string to date and filter it. it is maybe Silly .but i can't find any way

Comment: i use this method for change filter field [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861079/convert-data-between-actionresult-and-view)